# CFBundleDocumentTypes with Photo Library / Camera Roll

Tags: ios, openurl, cfbundledocumenttypes

I've added CFBundleDocumentTypes (public.png, public.jpeg, public.jpg, public.gif) to the Info.plist file. When I view an image in the "Mail" or "Messages" apps and click the "actions" menu button, I'm prompted to "Open Image in [My App]" ... however, when I view an image in the Photo Library / Camera Roll, I'm only prompted with "Facebook", "Twitter", and "Flickr".

Am I missing any settings in the plist file (pictured below)? Or does an app need special permissions to appear in the "actions" menu while browsing the photo gallery?

[image: CFBundleDocumentTypes row in Info.plist]

Comment: This has been covered a few times. File a complaint with Apple. The Photos app and the Mail app do not offer 3rd party apps as an option for opening images. There is nothing you can do to make this work with those two apps.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, will do. is working for me in "Mail" though.

Comment: OK, under mail I can get it to work if I first do a "QuickView".

Comment: so why other application appears? like dropbox, whatsup etcc?

Comment: On IOS8 now is possiible , refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988328/how-to-make-my-ios-app-visible-in-photo-sharing-options-like-facebook-and-twitte