# App is not showing in photo gallery on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, gallery

I have an application for uploading files and I want my app to show up when the user clicks on the iPad photo gallery/camera roll.  Also, I need it to show videos shot with the camera.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is my DocumentTypes list in my plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Audio</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.mp3</string>
            <string>public.mpeg-4-audio</string>
            <string>com.apple.m4a-audio</string>
            <string>public.audio</string>
            <string>com.apple.protected-​mpeg-4-audio</string>
            <string>public.aifc-audio</string>
            <string>com.apple.coreaudio-​format</string>
            <string>public.aiff-audio</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.waveform-​audio</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Video</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.movie</string>
            <string>public.avi</string>
            <string>public.mpeg-4</string>
            <string>public.mpeg</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.windows-​media-wmv</string>
            <string>com.apple.m4v.video</string>
            <string>public.video</string>
            <string>public.3gpp2</string>
            <string>public.3gpp</string>
            <string>com.apple.quicktime-movie</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Image</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>GIF image</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.compuserve.gif</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PNG image</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>TIFF image</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.tiff</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>JPEG image</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>OpenDocument Spreadsheet</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>org.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet</string>
            <string>org.oasis-open.opendocument.spreadsheet</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>OpenDocument Presentation</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>org.oasis.opendocument.presentation</string>
            <string>org.oasis-open.opendocument.presentation</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>OpenDocument Text</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>org.oasis.opendocument.text</string>
            <string>org.oasis-open.opendocument.text</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>OpenDocument Graphics</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>org.oasis.opendocument.graphics</string>
            <string>org.oasis-open.opendocument.graphics</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Microsoft PowerPoint</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt</string>
            <string>org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Microsoft Excel</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.excel.xls</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Microsoft Word</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.word.wordml</string>
            <string>org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: what you mean with "I want my app to show up when the user clicks on the iPad photo gallery/camera roll."?

Comment: You are not supposed to mess with `.plist` file. You need to implement `UIImagePickerViewController` delegate methods. See Apple Sample Code : [Using UIImagePickerController to Select Pictures and Take Photos](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196)

Comment: Yes DaSilva.  That's what I mean.

Comment: Rohan-patel, I have an app the uploads documents, photos and videos.  I want other apps to share via my app.  So when a user clicks on the share icon within CameraRoll, I want my app to show as an option.  The plist above is want I'm using, yet my app is not showing up.

Comment: I found the answer.  Apple doesn't allow it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403316/cfbundledocumenttypes-with-photo-library-camera-roll

Comment: so why other apps like whatsup, facebook, etcc appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  Apple does not allow 3rd party apps to show up in the camera roll.

[CFBundleDocumentTypes with Photo Library / Camera Roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403316/cfbundledocumenttypes-with-photo-library-camera-roll)

Comment: Hi, I can see several 3rd party apps ( Viber, Camu, KeepSafe, etc) visible in camera roll. 
But don't know how.

Answer (score -1):

I can't really understand what you are saying. But you could try making a album.

Comment: I have an app the uploads documents, photos and videos. I want other apps to share via my app. So when a user clicks on the share icon within CameraRoll, I want my app to show as an option. The plist above is what I'm using, yet my app is not showing up.  Email, Facebook and Flicket shows up but not my app.  How can I get my app to show?